# Making an IR transmitter with a range of 3-4 meters

Tags: sensor, infrared

I am designing a vehicle counter in a parking facility. What I have to do is to detect if a vehicle enters the 4 meter wide entering of the parking. I was initially trying to make an IR receiver and transmitter to detect a vehicle but I have no idea how to make it for 3-4 meters. Kindly tell me if already made sensors are available for this purpose or please give another idea how to implement it.

Comment: Is it underground facility? It probably won't work well at the daylight..

Comment: Any particular reason to not use a laser diode and a light filter and tube?

Comment: It would be even better if someone gives me a circuit diagram for the 4 meter range

Comment: nopes, it on underground, its out in the open

Comment: I have no information on a laser diode, if you would kindly tell a bit more detail about it?

Comment: @MubashiraZaman - If you are making a simple one-off detector you may have success with a laser pointer device pointed to a photo diode detector.

Comment: Typically, actually almost all of the time, this is done with an inductive loop in the ground.  Optical devices are prone to weather related failures, dirt, people purposely putting tape/gum/marker on them....  Ultrasonics aren't all that reliable for vehicles.  Induction loops are nearly foolproof.

Comment: Standard technique tends to be on modulating the source and filtering the detector to remove the effect of non-modulated stray light. Of course, the other standard technique is to use an inductive coil in the pavement rather than a "beam", so long as the vehicles you want to count contain adequate steel. A pressure sensor is a third approach. The beam will count people as well as cars - an inductive sensor generally will not, and a pressure sensor that requires a significant weight applied can avoid counting people, unless you have large people and also need to count small people on scooters.

Comment: IR transmitter and receiver pairs designed to span 3 or 4 meters are very common. Just search for something like "garage door IR sensor".